# How to configure a specific SonarLint Rule in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, sonarlint, roslyn-code-analysis, sonarlint-vs

I have SonarLint C# in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 on Windows 10, my solution is bound successfully with a SonarQube server, code analysis in my projects works fine, I can see the SonarLint warnings in the output window.

I want to configure the rule S103 ("Lines should not be too long") in my SonarLint plugin so that it warns me if a code line is longer than 200 instead of the builtin value of 150.

Is it possible to configure SonarLint rules? the nuget package only contains three dlls, I didn't find any config files

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet possible. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/issues/176) SonarLint issue and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarlint/$20maximumLineLength%7Csort:relevance/sonarlint/BXaU8FzvJT8/dDFLLC-5HwAJ) Google conversation. If you look in [SonarQube](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules#rule_key=csharpsquid%3AS103) then you can see that S103 has a parameter **maximumLineLength** that can be changed in your own SonarQube instance.

Comment: Note: the SonarLint issue linked to above describes a manual workaround that can be used to provide a configuration file for SonarC# rules.

Comment: The manual work around described by "duncanp" works fine for me. I only have to reference the SonarLint.xml file (that contains all the rule settings) once in all my projects. Now my VS2015 Warnings/issues match those of the SonarQube server.